# Query throws exception in SQL Server but not MySQL (outer reference error)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

SQL is not my strong suit so I was pretty happy when I came up with this query. It works fine when querying a MySQL database but gives me an error in a SQL Server database. Exact error is:

> Each Group By expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

I googled the error and tried to adjust my query accordingly but I just can't seem to get it to work. I've been stuck on it for a week. Anyone give me some pointers on it? Maybe there is a better way to do this? Server is SQL Server 2012 btw if that means anything.

It should be showing the results as below.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Category    |Total Customer Purchases|Monthly Limit|Customer Id|Last Transaction Date|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Free items  | 12                     | 10          | 635       | 2014-03-01
Food items  | 03                     | 10          | 635       | 2014-03-01
Other items | 05                     | 10          | 635       | 2014-03-01
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT (SELECT product_categories.cat_name
        FROM   product_categories
        WHERE  product_categories.cat_id = transaction_details.fk_category_id)
       AS
       'Category',
       Sum(transaction_details.quantity)
       AS 'Total Customer Purchases',
       (SELECT product_categories.cat_limit_for_month
        FROM   product_categories
        WHERE  product_categories.cat_id = transaction_details.fk_category_id)
       AS
       'Monthly Limit',
       transactions.cust_id
       AS 'Customer Id',
       transactions.trans_date
       AS 'Last Transaction Date'
FROM   transactions
       LEFT JOIN transaction_details
              ON transactions.link_to_trans_detail =
                 transaction_details.link_to_transactions
WHERE  transactions.cust_id = '25'
       AND transactions.trans_date >= '2014-03-01 19:25:44.000'
GROUP  BY 'Category'
HAVING transactions.trans_date >= '2014-03-01 19:25:44.000'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple improvements:

1. Use aliases for tables.  It is easier to type and intellisense will help you, too.
2. Include the product_categories table in your FROM clause.
3. Eliminate subqueries in your SELECT statement.  Even though it can work, it won't perform well at scale in most cases.
4. Consider using brackets around column names instead of apostrophes if you have spaces.  Intellisense will play better with this in many circumstances.  Or remove spaces altogether.
5. You don't need a HAVING clause if you already restricted your data in the WHERE clause.
6. Is there a reason you used a LEFT JOIN?  If data must exist on both sides, then consider changing this to JOIN.  If data isn't always there, then consider adding ISNULL() handling for the Category field to avoid NULLs.
7. I would recommend putting columns you intend to GROUP BY next to each other in the SELECT statement to make the code intent clearer.  It makes it really obvious what the data granularity is supposed to be.
8. Assuming this is an ad hoc or report query, you may want to consider using NOLOCK table hints if you have a low risk of dirty reads to avoid blocking or being blocked by queries.

Here's a sample version of what I mean:

```
SELECT pc.cat_name AS Category,
       t.cust_id AS [Customer Id],
       SUM(td.quantity) AS [Total Customer Purchases],
       MAX(pc.cat_limit_for_month) AS [Monthly Limit],
       MAX(t.trans_date) AS [Last Transaction Date]
FROM transactions t (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN transaction_details td (NOLOCK)
    ON t.link_to_trans_detail = td.link_to_transactions
LEFT JOIN product_categories pc (NOLOCK)
    ON td.fk_category_id = pc.cat_id
WHERE t.cust_id = '25'
AND t.trans_date >= '2014-03-01 19:25:44.000'
GROUP BY pc.cat_name
    , t.cust_id;
```